# new RoleManager<IdentityRole> error missing arguments in VS 2015

Tags: model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-identity-3

I want to implement User and Role Manager in VS 2015 using the Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final".

Among others I have created a class IdentityManager.

My main problem is creating a method to check the existence of a Role as follows.

```
public bool RoleExists(string name)
{
    var RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

    return RoleManager.RoleExists(name);
}
```

I keep getting the error on `new RoleManager<IdentityRole>`:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to roleValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, logger,contextAccessor"

Yes, basically all the parameters I am not specifying but I have no idea how to approach these.

I am very new at this and have been searching and trying for days now, if someone can just point me in the right direction I am willing to do the legwork and testing, I just need some documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar issue - it looks like the roles are not the best option in identity 3.0

This thread ([ASP .NET 5 MVC 6 Identity 3 Roles Claims Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966792/asp-net-5-mvc-6-identity-3-roles-claims-groups/34712765#34712765)) helped me get something working, but its sad that this is not better documented.

Here are my attempts at improving that. Asp.net.Identity (3.0.0.0-rc1-final)

in Startup.cs --> ConfigurationServices
            //Define your policies here, they are strings associated with claims types, that have claim strings... 
            //they need to be in AspNetUserClaims table, user id, department, Dev to be allowed access to the Dev policy
            //add the auth option, below that makes it work, and in the api controller, add the
            //[Authorize("Dev")] attribute
            //services.AddAuthorization(
            //    options =>
            //    {
            //        options.AddPolicy("Dev", policy => { policy.RequireClaim("department", "Dev"); });
            //    });